# Incorrect binding type of the reactive control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a strange problem with one of my reactive control `function` (below). It seems to be bound to a type `UserFunction` instead of just string as initialized in `*ngFor` section of my template.
If I execute `this.form.get('function').value` it returns UserFunction object - I would expect the string?

UserFunction definition:

```
export class UserFunction {
    id: string;
    userFunction: string;
}
```

Component:

```
userFunctions: UserFunction[] = [];
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
                scheduledDate: ['', Validators.required],
                function: ['', [Validators.required, this.functionValidator]],
                required: [''],
                userAvailability: [''],
              });
```

HTML template:

```
    <select formControlName="function" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.function.errors }">

               
                <option *ngFor="let item of userFunctions" [value]='item'>
                    {{ item.userFunction }}
                </option>
            </select>
```

Sorry I can't explain that simpler then that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the value for options correctly. Change your HTML as follows,

```
        <select formControlName="function" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.function.errors }">
            <option *ngFor="let item of userFunctions" [value]='item.userFunction'>
                {{ item.userFunction }}
            </option>
        </select>
```

Note that the value is now

```
[value]='item.userFunction'
```